# Reducing kernel overhead when reading a huge file with lazy bytestrings

Tags: linux, haskell, io

I'm reading a big file (1-10 GB) and computing some simple statistic over it, like counting a character. Streaming makes sense in this context, so I'm using lazy `ByteString`s. In particular, my `main` looks like

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- BSL.readFile "path"
  print $ computeStats contents
```

The details of `computeStats` are probably unimportant in this context.

When running this with `+RTS -sstderr`, I'm seeing this:

```
MUT     time    0.938s  (  1.303s elapsed)
```

Note the difference between CPU time and elapsed time. In addition to that, running under `/usr/bin/time` shows similar results:

```
0.89user 0.45system 0:01.35elapsed
```

The file I'm testing with is in `tmpfs`, so actual disk performance shouldn't be a factor.

How can I reduce the `system` time in this case? I tried setting explicitly the buffer size for the file handle (no statistically significant influence on the running times) as well as `mmap`ing the file and wrapping that into a `ByteString` (running times actually got worse). What else could be worth trying?

Comment: What does a non-Haskell program take? For instance, `/usr/bin/time sed /nonsensestring/d YOURFILE > /dev/null`

Comment: "The details of computeStats are probably unimportant in this context.".  Except they are _all_ that matter in this context.  There is nothing else to this program.  Just adding the bytes results in high productivity (MUT time out of total) and also high share of execution time being system time on my laptop.

Comment: Can you clarify:  how big is the file (i.e., 1G, 5G, or 10G) and what stats are you computing?  I can't replicate your timing results -- the system time suggests something on the order of 5G for a `tmpfs` file, but for a file that big, the user time seems insufficient for even something simple like counting nulls or computing a checksum (maybe 8-10 seconds?).

Comment: @BobDalgleish about the same `system`-time wise (I did `wc -w` though).
@ThomasM.DuBuisson the productivity is high in my case as well (that's great), but what I'm curious about is reducing the share of the system time. If you're really curious about the specifics of `computeStats`, then, well, here it is: https://github.com/0xd34df00d/hwc . BTW I know that code has a little off-by-one bug. I'll fix it, promise.
@K.A.Buhr in this particular case the file is 1G, and the stats are basically the same as `wc` (see the link above).

Comment: I'd recommend you avoid using lazy IO and use a proper streaming solution like `conduit` or something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it seems like there is something wonky going on with your machine.  When I run this program on a 1G file cached in memory or in an tmpfs filesystem (doesn't matter which), the system time is substantially smaller:

```
1.44user 0.14system 0:01.60elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 50256maxresident)
```

If you have any kind of other load or memory pressure that might account for these extra 300ms, I think you'll need to resolve that first before anything I say below will help, but...

Anyway, for my tests I've used a larger 5G testfile to make the system time easier to quantify.  As a baseline, the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define BUFLEN (1024*1024)
char buffer[BUFLEN];

int
main()
{
        int nulls = 0;
        int fd = open("/dev/shm/testfile5G.dat", O_RDONLY);
        while (read(fd, buffer, BUFLEN) > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < BUFLEN; ++i) {
                        if (!buffer[i]) ++nulls;
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n", nulls);
}
```

compiled with `gcc -O2` runs on my testfile with times:

```
real    0m2.035s
user    0m1.619s
sys     0m0.416s
```

For comparison, the Haskell program compiled with `ghc -O2`:

```
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- BSL.readFile "/scratch/buhr/testfile5G.dat"
  print $ BSL.foldl' go 0 contents
    where go :: Int -> Word8 -> Int
          go n 0 = n + 1
          go n _ = n
```

is quite a bit slower at the count but has nearly equivalent system time:

```
real    0m8.411s
user    0m7.966s
sys     0m0.444s
```

Simpler tests like `cat testfile5G.dat >/dev/null` all give consistent system time results, so it's safe to conclude that the overhead of the `read` calls, most likely the specific process of copying data from kernel to user address space, accounts for an appreciable fraction of the 410ms or so system time.

Contrary to your experience above, switching to `mmap` should reduce this overhead.  The Haskell program:

```
import System.Posix.IO
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import MMAP
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BS

-- exact length of file
len :: Integral a => a
len = 5368709120

main :: IO ()
main = do
  fd <- openFd "/scratch/buhr/testfile5G.dat" ReadOnly Nothing defaultFileFlags
  ptr <- newForeignPtr_ =<< castPtr <$>
    mmap nullPtr len protRead (mkMmapFlags mapPrivate mempty) fd 0
  let contents = BS.fromForeignPtr ptr 0 len
  print $ BS.foldl' (+) 0 contents
```

runs with about the same user time but substantially reduced system time:

```
real    0m7.972s
user    0m7.791s
sys     0m0.181s
```

Note that it's absolutely critical to use a zero-copy method of turning the mmapped area into a strict `ByteString` here.

At this point, I think we're probably down to the overhead of managing process page tables, and a C version using mmap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

size_t len = 5368709120;

int
main()
{
        int nulls = 0;
        int fd = open("/scratch/buhr/testfile5G.dat", O_RDONLY);
        char *p = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (!p[i]) ++nulls;
        }
        printf("%d\n", nulls);
}
```

has similar system time:

```
real    0m1.888s
user    0m1.708s
sys     0m0.180s
```

Comment: FYI, there are packages offering `mmap` for `ByteString`, both strict and (for reasons I don't understand) lazy.

Comment: Definitely something wonky on my machine, and I can't reproduce the problems with `mmap` anymore. I've replace `BS.readFile` with `mmap`ping function from the `bytestring-mmap` package (which seems to really do zero-copy), and I'm now getting 0.04 s of system time. Anyway, thanks for your detailed reply!